# Image not loading within a class

Tags: c#, xna, texture2d

I'm trying to load an image within a class:

```
myTexture = game.Content.Load<Texture2D>("myTexture");
```

The code compiles fine, but when it runs it says "file not found". But there is definitely a .jpg file called myTexture in the Solution Explorer.

I'm sure it's something simple, but what am I missing? I'm guessing I must be talking to the wrong directory somewhere, but I've reduced it to the most simple test program I can think of and still get the error.

I can load this image from the main game, so it is definitely a problem due to loading the image from within the class

Comment: Have you added the image to the content project? Is there a `myTexture.xnb` created in the content directory?

Comment: There is a file called myTexture.jpg underneath the section in the solution explorer called WindowsGame1(Content). There aren't any .xnb files but I've never had to use them before when I've loaded directly from the Game1 class

Comment: Please check the properties of the file. Especially if it's asset name is `myTexture`. The xnb file will be located in the output directory. Check that.

Comment: Actually there was a similar question. Maybe this could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10779935

Comment: Sorry another stupid question - what do you mean by the output directory?

Comment: Okay will have a look

Comment: no luck with this. Any more ideas?

Comment: Sorry to recomment on this but does any one have any other ideas? This is still causing me problems - I'd be happy to send over the whole solution if it helps?! What's weird is I can get it working in one project, but not in another

Answer (score 0):

Go over to the content view in VS, and click on the image file, you should get to see the properties of the image. One of these properties is "Build Action". This should be set to "Content", and if it's not, XNA won't try to build it into a .xnb file, and as such won't show up to Content.Load.

If you know the image is in the content folder, and you know it's set to "Content" as a build action, go to build, and rebuild the solution (should be F6 if I recall), and the .xnb should show up.

Comment: Okay the build action was set as compile, I've now changed it to Content, still get the same error though.

What I don't understand is that I can load the file just fine from within the game class, its only when I try and read it from within the class that the compiler can't find the file.

Comment: @user2056166 It sounds like the variable you assigned the texture to might be going out of scope.  Review the answer that XWaveX posted in the comments above, it describes this issue a bit further.  (You need to create a class-level variable to use the image outside of the `LoadContent` method.)

Comment: Have you rebuilt the solution since you've changed it? Also, if you haven't checked, the processor should be set to "Texture Processor", and the importer should be "Texture Importer".
The reason you can load the file with the File class is because that finds the actual .jpeg file, while Content.Load looks for things that passes through the content pipeline, transforming the files into the preprocessed .XNB that XNA wants. When it's set to compile, the .XNB never gets made, so the file class can find the .jpeg just fine, but Content.Load never gets the .XNB it wants.

Comment: @HyperAnthony I think I have created this variable. Basically I am trying to copy this example: http://codeforcake.com/blog/?p=226, and it works fine here